# Regarding the construction of the tensor bundle

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, differential-topology

Recall the construction of the tangent bundle: we write $$TM = \bigsqcup_{p \in M}T_p M$$ and define it as the prevector bundle with local trivializations $[\gamma] \mapsto (\gamma(0), (x\gamma)'(0))$ for $x$ a chart about the point $p = \gamma(0)$.

Let $T_l^k(V)$ be the space of all $\binom{k}{l}$-tensors on $V$, which we will look at as multilinear maps  $$V^* \times \cdots \times V^* \times V \times \cdots \times V \to \mathbb{R}$$ where there are $l$ copies of $V^*$ and $k$ copies of $V$. In similar fashion we define the bundle of $\binom{k}{l}$-tensors as $$T_l^k(M) = \bigsqcup_{p \in M}T_l^k(T_p M).$$ The proposed local trivialization is $\pi^{-1}(U) \to U \times \mathbb{R}^{n^{k + l}}$ where $\pi$ is the canonical projection onto $M$ and the map is given by mapping $$F \colon T_p^* M \times \cdots \times T_p^* M  \times T_p M \times \cdots \times T_p M \to \mathbb{R}$$

to $$(p, F_{i_1, \dots, i_k}^{j_1, \dots, j_l}).$$ The latter notation I am not sure I understand. The only way I can make sense of this (for dimensional reasons) is that $F_{i_1, \dots, i_k}^{j_1, \dots, j_l}$ is all different combinations $F(\omega^{j_1}, \dots, \omega^{j_l}, X_{i_1}, \dots, X_{i_k})$ where the entries are respective basis elements of $T^*_p(M)$ and $T_p M$.

Is this correct or have I misunderstood the notation?

Comment: Who is $U$ ? Anyway, in my opinion, $F^{j_1 \ldots j_\ell}_{i_1\ldots i_k}$ is the component of the $(\ell,k)$-tensor $F$ relatively to the bases $\left(\mathrm{d}x^{j_1},\ldots,\mathrm{d}x^{j_\ell}\right)$ and $\left(\partial_{i_1},\ldots,\partial_{i_k}\right)$ of $T^*_pM$ and $T_pM$, respectively, namely, $F^{j_1\ldots j_\ell}_{i_1\ldots i_k}=F\left(\mathrm{d}x^{j_1},\ldots,\mathrm{d}x^{j_\ell},\partial_{i_1},\ldots,\partial_{i_k}\right)$. It is called the index abstract notation for tensors.

Comment: $U$ is an open set in the smooth structure on the manifold $M$, that is there is a coordinate chart $(x, U).$ If I understand what you are writing correctly, it would mean that my understanding of the notation is correct, right? In particular, with this local trivialization the transition functions are merely the identity isomorphism.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right. The notations for basis elements of $T_pM$ are often written $\mathrm{d}x^i$ and those of $T^*_pM$ are often written $\partial_i$, but it depends on the author's taste.

Comment: Yes, the author did the same. (Although opposite, although you did that in your previous comment so probably a typo.) Then I think I understand, thanks a bunch!

Comment: You're welcome!